# Sitecore developer workstation requirement for Sitecore Experience Platform (XP Single)

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-assistant, setup

I am new in Sitecore and now I am trying to setup my machine. I want to ask you that what is a recommendation for developer workstation in terms of below points:

1. RAM
2. CPU
3. Disk
4. Any other specific requirement

Currently I am going to start work on Sitecore XP 9.3 but later I will work on Sitecore 10 with Docker so I am considering this point as well for developement machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This recommendation is for development environments on Windows 10 that use Docker Desktop:

RAM: 16GB of RAM is the minimum, 32GB of RAM is recommended. This depends on the number of instances and topologies you want to run (that is, the number of simultaneously running containers). For example, 16GB may be sufficient for XM1 or XP0 instances, but will probably have problems running a full XP1 instance.

A quad core, or higher, CPU.

At least 25GB of free disk space for Sitecore container images. SSD storage is highly recommended for optimal performance when downloading and running Docker containers.

I recommend you to have minimum 512 GB on your hard disk. On my old laptop I had 256 GB on my hard disk and I had to archive to cloud some old solutions/demo solution.

More information you can find here: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-xp-development-hardware-recommendations

https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/100/developer-tools/set-up-the-environment.html#prerequisites_body

Answer (score 1):

I get why the official minimum spec is so tempting to turn to, but like most of Sitecore's documentation its at best based on internal testing and not real world implementations. Like many others I feedback my experiences but they rarely if ever make it into the documentation.

With that said, please don't base your workstation spec on Sitecore's minimum hardware spec. If we work together someday I might have to deal with those choices! It's an innocent enough mistake, but so often a frustrating and expensive mistake to correct.

To start don't forget you need to accommodate everything else you'll be running locally - Visual studio, build tasks etc. try to pad any expectations you're making about your final application footprint before you invest and expect future unexpected scaling requirements...

Outside of resources your local environment configuration should mirror production as closely as possible, if you have multiple CD instances in prod have multiple locally. Don't wait until you have a minimum spec machine to find out that you need to troubleshoot an in proc issue that you can't replicate.

Plan for change, get a chassis & CPU that can take more RAM, get the latest gen processor. It's 2023 SSD's should only come in multiples of Terabyte.

These are the docker containers you'll likely run locally for XM1.

- 1 x CM
- 2 x CD
- 1 x ID
- 1 x Solr
- 1 x SQL
- 1 x Traefik

Interacting with a multisite CM instance with a helix solution loaded in VS maxes out an i7 with 32GB RAM. It will usually page heavily and sit at around 28GB while idling, under load there's the chance of an occasional blue screen.

My minimum workstation recommendation for a developer spec docker based XM project is 64GB, latest gen I9 you can find and at least a 1TB SSD.

If you're running XP topologies look for a box that can be expanded its not hard to find a motherboard with extra bays and a CPU that will support more RAM. If you have to buy a laptop, prioritize cooling over aesthetics.

In my experience the potential for productivity loss from under-spec'd workstations is huge and the cost of that will far out-weigh any initial outlay.